# when I add new book it isn't added?

Tags: javascript

this is simple java script application it supposed to Add a "NEW BOOK" button that brings up a form allowing users to input the details for the new book: author, title, link to an image. When they submit this form, it should add the book to the array and also render it onto the page.

my problem is that when clicking on ADD BOOK button and insert the book it doesn't work, despite that i make sure that it added to the array when i insert it but it doesn't render! what should i do to work correctly?

```js
let books = [{
    title: "Arbaoon",
    author: "Ahmad Shugairi",
    image: ""
  },
  {
    title: "harry potter",
    author: "J.K. Rowling",
    image: ""
  },
  {
    title: "the origin",
    author: "Dan Brown",
    image: ""
  },
  {
    title: "central park",
    author: "Guillaume Musso",
    image: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1538370965046-79c0d6907d47?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80"
  },
  {
    title: "1984",
    author: "George Orwell",
    image: "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/mountains-during-sunset-beautiful-natural-260nw-407021107.jpg"
  },
  {
    title: "book1",
    author: "John Doe",
    image: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/06/19/21/24/the-road-815297__340.jpg"
  }
];

function render() {

  const container = document.getElementById('container');
  const firstRow = document.createElement('div');
  const secondRow = document.createElement('div');
  const thirdRow = document.createElement('div');

  firstRow.classList.add('first_shelf');
  secondRow.classList.add('second_shelf');
  thirdRow.classList.add('third_shelf');

  container.appendChild(firstRow);
  container.appendChild(secondRow);
  container.appendChild(thirdRow);

  var images = [];
  var newArr = [];
  books.forEach((el, i) => {
    const imageContainer = document.createElement('div');
    const book = document.createElement('div');
    imageContainer.classList.add('imageContainer');

    book.classList.add(`book_${i}`);
    book.textContent = `${books[i].title} 
        by ${books[i].author}`
    const image = document.createElement('img');
    image.setAttribute('src', books[i].image);
    image.classList.add(`image_${i}`);
    imageContainer.appendChild(image);
    book.appendChild(imageContainer);

    newArr.push(book)

  });
  newArr.forEach((el, i) => {
    if (i <= 2) {
      firstRow.appendChild(el)
    } else if (i <= 5) {
      secondRow.appendChild(el)
    } else {
      thirdRow.appendChild(el)
    }
  });
}

function addNewBook() {

  const addBookButton = document.getElementById('addbook_btn');
  const submitButton = document.getElementById('submit_btn')
  addBookButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const form = document.getElementById('form');
    form.style.display = "block"
  });

  submitButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    form.style.display = "none";
    const bookTitleVal = document.getElementById('book_title').value;
    const autherVal = document.getElementById('auther').value;
    const imageLinkVal = document.getElementById('image_link').value;

    books.push({
      title: bookTitleVal,
      author: autherVal,
      mage: imageLinkVal
    });
  });
  render();
}
addNewBook();
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#container {
  height: 100vh;
}

.first_shelf {
  height: 20%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.second_shelf {
  height: 25%;
  background-color: red;
}

.third_shelf {
  height: 25%;
  background-color: seagreen;
}

.first_shelf,
.second_shelf,
.third_shelf {
  height: 30%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.first_shelf>div,
.second_shelf>div,
.third_shelf>div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 180px;
  height: 140px;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.imageContainer {
  background-color: chocolate;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.imageContainer>img {
  height: 90px;
  width: 100px
}

button {
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: crimson;
}

#form {
  display: none;
  background-color: darkgoldenrod;
  height: 160px;
  width: 250px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="addbook_btn">ADD BOOK</button>
  <form id="form">
    <label>book title</label>
    <input id="book_title">
    <label>auther</label>
    <input id="auther">
    <label>image link</label>
    <input id="image_link">
    <button type="submit" id="submit_btn"> submit </button>
  </form>
  <div id="container"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Your call to the `render()` function seems to be out of the event listener for `submitButton`. Try adding one more call of `render();` at the end of your event listener after `books.push`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only calling `render()` once on page load - which means you're never re-rendering the page content after the book list is changed. To fix it you can simply add another `render()` call within the submit button callback, so that the `container` node is re-populated every time a new book is added.

This presents a new issue, which is that `render()` doesn't clear the old divs, it only appends new ones. This causes additional shelves to be added *below* the first three, instead of replacing them. To fix this you can add a line `container.innerHTML = '';` in the `render()` function to clear the contents of the `container` node before adding the new shelves.

```js
let books = [
    {
        title: "Arbaoon",
        author: "Ahmad Shugairi",
        image: ""

    },
    {
        title: "harry potter",
        author: "J.K. Rowling",
        image: ""

    },
    {
        title: "the origin",
        author: "Dan Brown",
        image: ""

    },
    {
        title: "central park",
        author: "Guillaume Musso",
        image: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1538370965046-79c0d6907d47?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80"

    },
    {
        title: "1984",
        author: "George Orwell",
        image: "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/mountains-during-sunset-beautiful-natural-260nw-407021107.jpg"

    },
    {
        title: "book1",
        author: "John Doe",
        image: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/06/19/21/24/the-road-815297__340.jpg"

    }
  
];
function render(){

    const container = document.getElementById('container');
    const firstRow = document.createElement('div');
    const secondRow = document.createElement('div');
    const thirdRow = document.createElement('div');

    container.innerHTML = ''; //clear existing children of container

    firstRow.classList.add('first_shelf');
    secondRow.classList.add('second_shelf');
    thirdRow.classList.add('third_shelf');


    container.appendChild(firstRow);
    container.appendChild(secondRow);
    container.appendChild(thirdRow);


    var images = [];
    var newArr =[];
    books.forEach((el,i) => {
        const imageContainer = document.createElement('div');
        const book = document.createElement('div');
        imageContainer.classList.add('imageContainer');
        
        book.classList.add(`book_${i}`);
        book.textContent = `${books[i].title} 
        by ${books[i].author}`
        const image = document.createElement('img');
        image.setAttribute('src', books[i].image);
        image.classList.add(`image_${i}`);
        imageContainer.appendChild(image);
        book.appendChild(imageContainer);
        
        newArr.push(book)        

    });
    newArr.forEach((el,i) => {
            if (i <= 2) {
                firstRow.appendChild(el)
            } 
            else if( i <= 5) {
                secondRow.appendChild(el)
            }   
            else {
                thirdRow.appendChild(el)
            }
    });

}
function addNewBook(){
    
    const addBookButton = document.getElementById('addbook_btn');
    const submitButton = document.getElementById('submit_btn')
    addBookButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const form = document.getElementById('form');
        form.style.display = "block"
    });

    submitButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        form.style.display = "none";
        const bookTitleVal = document.getElementById('book_title').value;
        const autherVal = document.getElementById('auther').value;
        const imageLinkVal = document.getElementById('image_link').value;

        books.push({
            title: bookTitleVal,
            author: autherVal,
            mage: imageLinkVal

        });
  
        render();
       
    });
    render();

}
addNewBook();
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    
}
#container {
height: 100vh;
}

.first_shelf {
    height: 20%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: aqua;

}
.second_shelf {
    height: 25%;
   
    background-color: red;

}
.third_shelf {
    height: 25%;
    
    background-color: seagreen;

}
.first_shelf, .second_shelf, .third_shelf {
    height: 30%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

}
.first_shelf > div, .second_shelf > div, .third_shelf > div {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 180px;
    height: 140px;
    margin: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.imageContainer {
    background-color: chocolate;
    height: 90px;
    width:90px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.imageContainer > img {
    height: 90px;
    width:100px
}
button {
    height: 50px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: crimson;
}
#form {
    display: none;
    background-color: darkgoldenrod;
    height: 160px;
    width: 250px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <button id="addbook_btn">ADD BOOK</button>
     <form id="form"  >
        <label>book title</label>
        <input id="book_title"> 
        <label>auther</label>
        <input id="auther">
        <label>image link</label>
        <input id="image_link">
        <button type="submit" id="submit_btn"> submit </button>
    </form>
    <div id="container"></div>
    
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your render call should be inside the click callback of the submit button, can you try to place it there ?